# Четырнадцать тридцать два или четырнадцать тридцать две?

Tags: согласование

Проблема согласования рода, если минут одна или две.
Что мы делаем, когда называем текущее время?

а) Просто называем числа и цифры. Например, одиннадцать ноль ноль. Если в примере из заголовка мы поступаем так же, согласование рода не нужно.

б) Опускаем слова "часы" и "минуты". Четырнадцать [часов] тридцать две [минуты]. Тогда согласование требуется.

Какой вариант принят в литературе? В устной речи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грамоте.ру задали схожий вопрос, не про время, а про температуру, где тоже требовалось согласование. 
Вот что они ответили.

### Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Интересный вопрос. Рекомендаций в справочных пособиях найти не удалось, поэтому обратимся к примерам из художественной литературы (которые можно подобрать благодаря «Национальному корпусу русского языка»). На конструкцию «столько-то градусов и один/одна» в корпусе только один пример: Иона Овсеич вздрогнул, сестра вынула из-под мышки термометр, ***тридцать восемь и одна,*** сказала, к вечеру подымется еще... А. Львов, Двор. ***А вот примеров на конструкцию «столько-то градусов и два/две» гораздо больше:*** Нормальная моя температура ― ***тридцать три и два.*** Е. Шварц, Снежная королева. Его нужно обязательно подкармливать, понемножку, но чаще. Утром тридцать ***пять и два было?*** Вот видите; это так же опасно, как большой жар. М. Осоргин, Сивцев Вражек. «Он ― путешественник… ― вернувшись, сказала старушка. ― ***Тридцать семь и две…*** Он пешком в Туркестан шел. Ты его не обижай, Катя» В. Каверин, Два капитана. Видишь, ни то ни сё, ***тридцать семь и две.*** Было бы тридцать восемь, так каждому ясно. Я тебя освободить не могу. На свой страх, если хочешь, останься. А. Солженицын, Один день Ивана Денисовича. «Какая температура тела?» ― спросил Николай, отключив микрофон. ***«Тридцать восемь и две,*** ― ответил врач. ― Это не опасно ― волнение…» В. Высоцкий, Как-то так все вышло... ***У бабушки было тридцать девять и два.*** Зашелушившимися губами она отказалась от аспирина и от чая с малиной. Н. Крыщук, Отступление.

> Как видно из примеров, в рассматриваемых конструкциях возможны варианты: женский род поддерживается тем, что подразумевается слово (одна) десятая, (две) десятых, но отсутствие этого слова способствует употреблению в мужском роде.

P.S. Возможно, и в этом случае дело обстоит также.

Comment: Спасибо! Это действительно про то, что нужно, и работает, думаю, одинаково. Значит, можно и так, и так. Постараюсь до конца недели найти время собрать ещё подобную статистику по времени и тогда закрою вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Даже если мы не произносим слова "часы" и "минуты", мы имеем в виду именно часы и минуты. Поэтому "четырнадцать тридцать две".

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, чем у вас а) отличается от б).
Я бы сказал, что возможны оба варианта. Не думаю, что это как-то регламентируется.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не смог ответить на вопрос о времени "сейчас четырнадцать тридцать один" - диссонанс с подразумеваемыми минутами заметнее, чем в случае "... два". Если речь идёт о цифрах на табло, может оказаться удобным продиктовать их в такой форме для записи (даже если это время: на часах /цифры/ четырнарнадцать тридцать один), но когда вы в обычной обстановке говорите о времени, это просто сокращение: вы пропускаете слова, без которых понятен остальной смысл. Сохранение согласованного с подразумеваемыми минутами рода числительного делает выражение доходчивее.